# Inline Form Input and Submit Button Misaligned at Screen Widths < 576 px

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4, inline

I'm using Bootstrap 4.2.1 and I have an inline form that displays perfectly at viewport widths > 575 px:
[image: Form elements nicely line up]
However, at viewport widths < 576 px, the form submit button becomes misaligned, dropping slightly:
[image]
I've replicated the problem here: https://www.codeply.com/go/hW1xZkJXQ9

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="Email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control mr-2" id="Email" placeholder="user@gmail.com">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this happens at smaller screen widths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing without having to customize the core Bootstrap CSS.

I learned that `.form-inline` [only displays form elements inline at screen widths of at least 576 px](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#inline-forms). Additionally, I was incorrectly using `.form-group` along with `.form-inline` when I should have been using `.input-group` on the inputs, as was pointed out above. But this still didn't allow me to keep things inline at narrow screen widths of less than 576 px.

Therefore, I abandoned `.form-inline` altogether and instead used a [form grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#form-grid) approach using Bootstrap's built-in grid classes. I used `.form-row` and treated the inline form elements as normal columns:

Updated Codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/hwBPwM6qTV

```
<div class="container">
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-8 col-sm-5 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="Email">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email"  placeholder="user@gmail.com">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
        </div>        
    </div> <!-- .form-row -->
</form>
</div>
```

This keeps everything inline at very narrow screen widths:
[image: inline form at narrow screen widths]

Obviously, the columns can be changed to suit the needs of the particular application or preference.

Answer (score 0):

after 576px, `form-control` remove `inline block` property, so i will add it for all resolution.

and for btn, i am using `mt-n3 mt-sm-0` bootstrap class.

updated codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/35ENnBhxpA

```css
body {
    padding:100px;
}
.form-control {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="Email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control mr-2" id="Email" placeholder="user@gmail.com">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-n3 mt-sm-0" type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply; however, I'm looking for a solution that does not involve modifying the Bootstrap CSS (in your example, you're changing the CSS properties of the `.form-control` class). I worry that might have unforeseen consequences.